# Display map coordinate in input fields

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have two input fields and a map under them, what i want to do is to display the longitude and latitude when i click on the map in any location, how can i do that? here is my code:

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Latitude</label>
    <input placeholder="Latitude">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Longitude</label>
    <input placeholder="Longitude">
  </div>

<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function myMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.12),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click event listener on map.

below is the code for that

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    alert(event.latLng);

});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Latitude</label>
    <input placeholder="Latitude" id="lat">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Longitude</label>
    <input placeholder="Longitude" id="lang">
  </div>

<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function myMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.12),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    
     var myLatLng = event.latLng;
     var lat = myLatLng.lat();
     var lng = myLatLng.lng();
     
      document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
      document.getElementById("lang").value = lng;
   
});
    
    
  }
  
 
</script>
<script>

</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=myMap"></script>

<script>
  
</script>
```

Note : You can't use google maps without api key. The usage is free until your application reaches 25.000 calls per day on 90 consecutive days.

Comment: its not working i tried running it in the snippet but it gave me errors

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }", "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined",